# which has a better performance filter / all in django queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

let's say I have a model named `Best`

I am wondering if using `Best.objects.all()` would be a better choice or `Best.objects.filter(this=that)` would be better performance overall if I do not need to query everything

Comment: They're totally different things, but as you've asked... If you've got a table with 1 million rows. Calling `.all()` needs to return 1 million rows. If `this == that` for only 1 of those rows, you'd better call `.filter(this=that)` so you only need to pull 1 row from the db.

Comment: @markwalker_ doesn't calling `Best.objects.filter(this=that)` would still go for the million rows to make sure that all of `this=that` are being searched unless I use `Best.objects.filter(this=that).first()` then it'll query the first and stop

Comment: It would still go through a million rows, but action would take place in the database, rather than transferring the data to python, so it's more efficient.

Comment: @markwalker_ thx a lot for the explanation.  I will keep that in mind and using `filter` instead :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Best.objects.all()` then using Python to test `if this == that` isn't a good idea. `Best.objects.filter(this = that)` is way better performance wise as the database performs the check. Only the objects that satisfy the check will become available in Python.

Let's use another example: `amount = len(Best.objects.all())` would be much slower than `amount = Best.objects.all().count()` since Python doesn't have to work it out.

Comment: thanks a lot, I didn't know there's such difference before.  esp the `len` and `count()` I will remember using `count()`  but then this being said, why would people still use `len` though?

Comment: Some people don't know `count` is more efficient and I'm guessing others don't know it exists.